# Is there anyway to sort an index before the aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following index template

```
{
  "index_patterns": "notificationtiles*",
  "order": 1,
  "version": 1,
  "aliases": {
    "notificationtiles": {}
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "influencerId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "friendId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "sponsorshipCharityId": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
      },
      "createdTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "index": false
      },
      "updatedTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis",
        "index": false
      },
      "createdDate": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updatedDate": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the following query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "influencerId": "52407710-f7be-49c1-bc15-6d52363144a6"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "type": "friend_completed_sponsorship"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "friendId": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "friendId",
                "size": 2
            },
            "aggs": {
                "latest": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "createdDate": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "_source": {
                            "includes": [
                                "sponsorshipCharityId",
                                "message",
                                "createdDate"
                            ]
                        },
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which returns

```
{
    "took": 72,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 12,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "friendId": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 7,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "cf750fd8-998f-4dcd-9c88-56b2b6d6fce9",
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "latest": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 3,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "notificationtiles-1",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "416a8e07-fd72-46d4-ade1-b9442ef46978",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "createdDate": "2020-06-24T17:35:17.816842Z",
                                        "sponsorshipCharityId": "336de13c-f522-4796-9218-f373ff0b4373",
                                        "message": "Contact Test 788826 Completed Sponsorship!"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1593020117816
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "93ab55c5-795f-44b0-900c-912e3e186da0",
                    "doc_count": 2,
                    "latest": {
                        "hits": {
                            "total": {
                                "value": 2,
                                "relation": "eq"
                            },
                            "max_score": null,
                            "hits": [
                                {
                                    "_index": "notificationtiles-1",
                                    "_type": "_doc",
                                    "_id": "66913b8f-94fe-49fd-9483-f332329b80dd",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                        "createdDate": "2020-06-24T17:57:17.816842Z",
                                        "sponsorshipCharityId": "dbad136c-5002-4470-b85d-e5ba1eff515b",
                                        "message": "Contact Test 788826 Completed Sponsorship!"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        1593021437816
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'd like the results to include the latest documents (ordered by createdDate desc), for example the following document

```
            {
                "_index": "notificationtiles-1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "68a2a0a8-27aa-4347-8751-d7afccfa797d",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": "68a2a0a8-27aa-4347-8751-d7afccfa797d",
                    "influencerId": "52407710-f7be-49c1-bc15-6d52363144a6",
                    "friendId": "af342805-1990-4794-9d67-3bb2dd1e36dc",
                    "message": "Contact Test 788826 Completed Sponsorship!",
                    "type": "friend_completed_sponsorship",
                    "sponsorshipCharityId": "b2db72e6-a70e-414a-bf8b-558e6314e7ec",
                    "createdDate": "2020-06-25T17:35:17.816842Z",
                    "updatedDate": "2020-06-25T17:35:17.816876Z",
                    "createdTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": 1593021437817,
                    "updatedTimestampEpochInMilliseconds": 1593021437817
                }
            }
```

I need to get the 2 latests documents grouped by friendId with the latest document per friendId. The part of grouping by friendId with the latest document per friendId, works fine. However, I'm unable to sort the index by createdDate desc before the aggregation happens.

essentially, i'd like to sort the index by createdDate desc, before the aggregation takes place. I don't want to have a parent aggregate by createdDate since that wouldn't result in unique friendId. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the order property of your terms aggregation. By default they are ordered by hit count. You want them to be ordered by the max createdDate. So you should add a sub aggregation to calculate the max createdDate, and then you can use the ID of that aggregation to order the parent terms aggregation.

Comment: Thanks. However, since the parent aggregation by 'friendId' takes place first (and i only want the first 2), it already excludes the latest documents (by createdDate). That's why the solution would need to, in some way, sort the index before the initial aggregation takes place.

Comment: From what I can tell, the "order" field is what ranks the term aggregation, and the "size" field determines how many are taken from the top of the results. This means that even though the max-date aggregation is is subordinate to the terms aggregations, it is used to rank the terms buckets. The top two friendId values returned should therefore be those that have the most recent createdDate. I did a simple test on an index I've been using, and found that the top results didn't change when I altered the "size" property of the terms aggregation.

Comment: This is still impossible if the top aggregation needs to be a composite aggregation.  Which is currently my problem at the moment

Comment: In a composite aggregation, you can sort the keys from composite sources themselves, but my composite keys are UUIDs, not dates, so I guess my only possible solution is to add another field to each record of my groups to be a group date that they all share with the uuid, this way, the composite keys created can then be sorted during the composite aggregation source's sort.  Sigh....  At least it might be possible.  back to work

Comment: Another thing I tried was an attempt to sort my query by the date field before running the composite aggregation, but it does not appear to function in that way.